Group two nested variables by row with gtsummary
Let's assume the following dataset :
df <- data.frame(
  classification = c("independant professions", "independant professions", "workers", "workers"),
  occupations = c("Lawyer", "Doctor", "Mason", "Painter")
)


Created on 2024-06-08 with reprex v2.1.0
Is there a way in gtsummary to achieve a summary table like the one below ?

Possible similar question : gtsummary::tblsummary() "by = " as rows instead of columns
Thanks,
